# Creating time intervals using sqldf package

Tags: r, time, timestamp, dataframe, sqldf

This is what my data frame looks like.

I want to create time intervals of 15 mins or 30 mins and have the sum of `No_Words` for all timestamps in that time interval. I need this to plot the average number of words per time interval.

How should I go about it?

Also, I would really like to know if a solution is possible using `sqldf` package.

```
               Time                 No_Words
1   2013-11-17 13:37:00                    6    
2   2013-11-17 13:37:00                   16    
3   2013-11-17 13:37:00                   18    
4   2013-11-17 13:37:00                   12    
5   2013-11-17 14:03:00                    5    
6   2013-11-17 14:03:00                   20    
7   2013-11-17 14:04:00                    4    
8   2013-11-17 17:21:00                   39    
9   2013-11-17 22:48:00                   19    
10  2013-11-17 22:48:00                   12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# generate example data, 30 min intervals
set.seed(1)
dateseq <- seq(as.POSIXct("2013-11-17"), as.POSIXct("2013-11-18"), by="min")
df <- data.frame(Time=dateseq[sample(1:length(dateseq), 500)],
                 No_Words=sample(1:100, 500, replace=T))
groups <- cut.POSIXt(df$Time, breaks="30 min")
```

The hard way using `sqldf`:

```
library(sqldf)
df$groups <- groups
agg <- sqldf("select groups, avg(No_Words) from df group by groups", row.names=T)
row.names(agg) <- agg[,1]
agg <- as.matrix(agg)
class(agg) <- "numeric"
par(mar=c(2,10,0,0)); barplot(agg[,2], horiz=TRUE, las=1)
```

The easy way using e.g. `tapply`:

```
agg <- tapply(df$No_Words, list(groups), mean)
par(mar=c(2,10,0,0)); barplot(agg, horiz=TRUE, las=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

**sqldf** Here is an sqldf solution where the input data frame is `DF`:

```
library(sqldf)

min15 <- 15 * 60 # in seconds
ans <- fn$sqldf("select
       t.Time - t.Time % $min15 as Time, 
       sum(t.No_Words) as No_Words
    from DF t 
    group by Time")
plot(No_Words ~ Time, ans, type = "o")
```

giving:

```
> ans
                 Time No_Words
1 2013-11-17 13:30:00       52
2 2013-11-17 14:00:00       29
3 2013-11-17 17:15:00       39
4 2013-11-17 22:45:00       31
```

**With dense grid** If a dense grid is wanted then we will need a grid data frame, `G`, which we join with the prior `ans` (Note that sqldf pulls in the chron package so we use its `trunc` function):

```
# create grid G
rng <- range(as.POSIXct(trunc(as.chron(DF$Time), 15 / (24 * 60))))
G <- data.frame(Time = seq(rng[1], rng[2], by = min15))

ans2 <- sqldf("select Time, coalesce(No_Words, 0) as No_Words 
         from (select * from G left join ans using(Time))")
plot(No_Words ~ Time, ans2, type = "o")
```

The first few rows of `ans2` are:

```
> head(ans2)

                 Time No_Words
1 2013-11-17 13:30:00       52
2 2013-11-17 13:45:00        0
3 2013-11-17 14:00:00       29
4 2013-11-17 14:15:00        0
5 2013-11-17 14:30:00        0
6 2013-11-17 14:45:00        0
```

**zoo** We also show a zoo solution:

```
library(zoo)
library(chron)
FUN <- function(x) as.POSIXct(trunc(as.chron(x), 15 / (24 * 60)))
z <- read.zoo(DF, FUN = FUN, aggregate = sum)
plot(z)
```

which gives for `z`:

```
> z
2013-11-17 13:30:00 2013-11-17 14:00:00 2013-11-17 17:15:00 2013-11-17 22:45:00 
             52                  29                  39                  31
```

**Note:** We used this data and, in particular, `Time` is of class `"POSIXct"`:

```
Lines<- " Time            No_Words
1   2013-11-17 13:37:00                    6    
2   2013-11-17 13:37:00                   16    
3   2013-11-17 13:37:00                   18    
4   2013-11-17 13:37:00                   12    
5   2013-11-17 14:03:00                    5    
6   2013-11-17 14:03:00                   20    
7   2013-11-17 14:04:00                    4    
8   2013-11-17 17:21:00                   39    
9   2013-11-17 22:48:00                   19    
10  2013-11-17 22:48:00                   12   
"

raw <- read.table(text = Lines, skip = 1)
DF <- data.frame(Time = as.POSIXct(paste(raw$V2, raw$V3)), No_Words = raw$V4)
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer is not with sqldf, but with the base R functions `aggregate` and `cut`:

```
## If your "Time" column is not an actual time object, 
##    convert it to one before proceeding.
mydf$Time <- as.POSIXct(mydf$Time)
```

`cut` can create time bins. We'll use that to do our aggregation. You could use the `formula` notation, but I've used the `list` approach so that it is easy to specify the resulting column names:

```
## Aggregate data in 30 minute chunks
aggregate(list(No_Words = mydf$No_Words), 
          list(Time = cut(mydf$Time, "30 min")), FUN = mean)
#                  Time No_Words
# 1 2013-11-17 13:37:00 11.57143
# 2 2013-11-17 17:07:00 39.00000
# 3 2013-11-17 22:37:00 15.50000

## Aggregate data into 15 minute chunks
aggregate(list(No_Words = mydf$No_Words), 
          list(Time = cut(mydf$Time, "15 min")), FUN = mean)
#                  Time  No_Words
# 1 2013-11-17 13:37:00 13.000000
# 2 2013-11-17 13:52:00  9.666667
# 3 2013-11-17 17:07:00 39.000000
# 4 2013-11-17 22:37:00 15.500000
```